# Export to CSV file with windows path

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

I'm using Putty to connect to Postgres 9.6.

I'm trying to export to csv five but I keep getting this error:

> ERROR:  relative path not allowed for COPY to file

This is my code:

```
COPY (select * from res_users) TO E'G:\\Test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: `copy` runs **on the server** and creates the file **on the server**. So the path needs to comply with the file system rules for the server operating system.  If you are using Putty Postgres most probably runs on a Linux machine, so a Windows path isn't valid there to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So what do I need to do? I'm trying to use `\copy` too. It doesn't has error neither creating the file